# sql Complex data sorting with start_time and end_time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table named 'activity' that contains activity data. The important columns are 'start_time' and 'end_time' which contain string (YYYY-MM-DD) to represent when the activity starts and ends.

I want to get some records at one time.Kind of like paging.The problem is I need to sort the data.
Sorting rules:

```
 1:data which current time between start_time and end_time row first
 2:data which current time before start_time second
 3:data which current time after end_time last
```

Events:

```
--------------------------------
ID | START_TIME      | END_TIME|
--------------------------------
1  | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-14 |
2  | 2013-07-01 | 2013-07-10 |
3  | 2013-07-30 | 2013-07-31 |
4  | 2013-06-15 | 2013-08-21 |
5  | 2013-06-22 | 2013-06-25 |
------------------------------
```

Don't you know how to do that? Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Example:
  Today is 2013-06-23.I need data like this:

```
 --------------------------------
ID | START_TIME      | END_TIME|
--------------------------------
4  | 2013-06-15 | 2013-08-21 |
5  | 2013-06-22 | 2013-06-25 |
2  | 2013-07-01 | 2013-07-10 |
3  | 2013-07-30 | 2013-07-31 |
1  | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-14 |
------------------------------
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Then edit your question to show us how the result should look on say 25th July 2013

Comment: Hey,buddy.I show the data on 2013-06-23.

Answer (score 1):

You can order conditionally on `case` like this:

```
select *
from table
order by 
case 
  when '2013-06-23' >= start_time and '2013-06-23' <= end_time then 0
  when '2013-06-23' < start_time then 1
  else 2 end,
start_time, end_time, id;
```

Comment: I tried this before.I need the data like the example.Thanks buddy.